# Sending emails in Django with NameCheap email account

Tags: django, django-email, namecheap

I set up an email account with NameCheap that I use with my Django app. Below is my email configuration based on information provided by NameCheap

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'news@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'WebsiteTitle <news@mydomain.com>'
```

Now when I use `send_mail()` django function (eg. after registration) it is like playing roulette - one time it works properly and sends out an email, another time it throws an error saying

> SMTPServerDisconnected at /reset-password/
> Connection unexpectedly closed

As if something was wrong with my email configuration.

Do you have any idea what might cause it or how to try to fix it or debug it? Is it more likely NameCheap or Django?

Comment: Turn on SMTP tracing to see the entire dialog.

Comment: Your SMTP server might be blocking your request and you can't send too many mail at a time if you are using namecheap  low budget hosting plan.

Comment: @JohnHanley how do I do it?

Comment: I do not develop in Django, so I do not know. Google search for the mail library that you are using. Turning on debugging and tracing are commonly used features. Then there are tools like WireShark to capture network traffic.

Answer (score 3):

hope you solved it otherwise for any other person who is stuck.
FOR EMAIL HOST USE "smtp.privateemail.com", the other parameters are ok.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.privateemail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'news@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('EMAIL_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'WebsiteTitle <news@mydomain.com>'
```